# Separation of points in a Poisson point process

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have a Poisson point process $\mu$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with driving measure absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.  For any $\epsilon > 0$, I can choose a rectangle $R$ large enough such that

$$\mathbb{P} \{\mu(R) > 0 \} > 1 - \epsilon.$$

Now, on this event $\{ \mu(R) > 0 \}$, I would like to say that with high probability, the points of $\mu$ that are in the rectangle $R$ are separated.  Namely, calling the points $(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_n, y_n) \in R$, I would like to know that points are not "too close" together.  That is, I would like information on

$$f(\delta) = \mathbb{P} \{ || (x_i, y_i) - (x_j, y_j) || > \delta \text{ for all }i,j \}.$$

Obviously this will depend on the driving measure (and the rectangle), but I would like to know how large I can take $\delta$ while keeping $f(\delta)$ close to $1$.

Any reference would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: See Proposition 1.1.3 of http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/43/87/68/PDF/FnT1.pdf

Comment: @Stelios Thanks for the reference, it looks nice.  You're right, the way I originally formulated the question, it was equivalent to proving the point process is simple.  I've edited the question.

Comment: Considering your modified question, I would start by considering $f(\delta)$ when conditioned on $R$ having $N< \infty$ uniformly distributed points, which I believe is a difficult problem. (Note that if you extend $R$ to be the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $f(\delta) = 0$ for all $\delta>0$, as, with an infinite number of points, there will always exist pairs of points that are arbitrarily close together.) Maybe a more useful and tractable notion of "closeness" is the distribution of the distance to the nearest neighbor (see Example 1.4.7 of the above reference)

Comment: That is example is helpful.  I think to get my result, I need to integrate the probability given in the example against the Poisson point process (a random measure of atoms) conditioned on the rectangle being non-empty.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume first that $\mu$ has constant intensity $\lambda$, then the number $N_R$ of points in $R$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda|R|$ and, conditionally on $N_R$, the points of the process in $R$ are i.i.d. and uniform in $R$. The distance $D$ between any two points of the process in $R$ is such that $P(D\leqslant x)\leqslant\pi x^2/|R|$ for every nonnegative $x$. Each point has $N_R-1$ neighbors hence, still conditionally on $N_R$, the probability that there exists two points in $R$ at distance less than $\delta$ is at most $N_R(N_R-1)\pi\delta^2/|R|$, which implies that $$f(\delta)\geqslant1-E(N_R(N_R-1))\pi\delta^2/|R|=1-\lambda^2|R|\pi\delta^2.$$
In particular, $f(\delta)\geqslant1-\varepsilon$ for every $\delta$ such that $$\delta^2\leqslant\frac{\varepsilon}{\pi|R|\lambda^2}.$$
The same bounds hold if the intensity of $\mu$ is uniformly at most $\lambda$.

Comment: Nice answer. However, I am wondering whether conditioning on $N_R$ changes $P(D>x)$, i.e., $P(D>x|N_R \textrm{ points in } R) \neq e^{-\lambda\pi x^2}$, since $\mu$, conditioned on the number of points in $R$, is no longer a poisson point process.

Comment: And you are right to wonder... See revised version.

Comment: @Did:  Sorry to revive an old post, but if the intensity measure is not a constant, then the points aren't uniformly distributed in the rectangle, correct?

Comment: Of course (but you know the answer, don't you?).

Comment: I think that the points should be be i.i.d with distribution $\nu(\cdot)/\nu(R)$, where $\nu$ is the driving measure of $mu$, though I'm having difficulty proving this.

Comment: These are basics of Poisson processes. Which textbook are you using?

Comment: Daley and Vere-Jones, but I'm not a big fan.  Any recommendations on a book?

Comment: A classics is *Poisson Processes* (Oxford Studies in Probability) by J. F. C. Kingman.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out, and thanks in general for all the help!